# Sysadmin is unable to create database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-administration, windows-server-2016

I am trying to install a MSI that is supposed to create database and install all the applications that go with it. Every time when it comes to the create database line the MSI is failing complaining

> "The user does not have access to create database"

But in reality user has sysadmin access on the SQL Server. When I try to create DB directly through SSMS it works fine.

Its a 2016 SQL Server installed on a 2016 Windows Server.

Comment: just for giggles, make sure user has dbcreator role assigned.

Comment: You've run the MSI as administrator? (Elevated permissions).

Comment: @arcee123 still getting "An error occurred while adding database to the server" :(

Comment: @DaleBurrell yes i am running it as admin.

Comment: are you using user/name password? or windows authentication?

Answer (score 0):

> Members of sysadmin role are by default members of dbcreator server role therefore they 
>     can create databases too.
>   you can replace your login name and run below query and check.

```
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'yourloginname', @rolename = N'dbcreator'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

To me the problem sounds like the installer is using a different user context than expected. But it can be difficult to track down because this error is not logged by default and the error itself is actually very generic.

Going into some details, this seems like a permission error. However the error thrown on that is 262, which is a generic ' permission denied in database '. As viewable through this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE language_id = 1033 AND message_id = 262
```

Which has the is_event_logged value set to 0 and as text value:

> %ls permission denied in database '%.*ls'.

We can enable the logging for this event (so it's viewable in SQL Server Logs) however it will then log ALL missing permission events, which depending on how busy the Server is can be a lot and might be undesireable.

However to further find out under what context the installer is doing it's operations, we can enable it with:

```
EXEC sp_altermessage @message_id = 262, @parameter = 'WITH_LOG' ,@parameter_value = 'true'
```

When the installer is running and the error is being thrown the event should be in the SQL Server log (example below is done simply with an unpriviliged user in TSQL):

[image: Snap SQL Log]

Now knowing the SPID value we can find out the user context using the sp_who2 command. Which shows the associated Login.

```
EXEC sp_who2
```

This Login would need to be of sysadmin/dbcreator or simply have the CREATE DATABASE Server permission.

I'd strongly advise to run:

```
EXEC sp_altermessage @message_id = 262, @parameter = 'WITH_LOG' ,@parameter_value = 'false'
```

When done to revert the logging of this error to the SQL Server logs. Hopefully this helps narrowing the problem down.